# How do I use the AudioUnit to play the audio stream from server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, stream, playback, audiounit

```
- (void)openPlayThreadWithRtmpURL:(NSString *)rtmpURL {
spx_int16_t *input_buffer;

do {
    if (self.rtmpDelegate) {
        [self.rtmpDelegate evenCallbackWithEvent:2000];
    }

    //init speex decoder and config;
    speex_bits_init(&dbits);
    dec_state = speex_decoder_init(&speex_wb_mode);

    speex_decoder_ctl(dec_state, SPEEX_GET_FRAME_SIZE, &dec_frame_size);

    input_buffer = malloc(dec_frame_size * sizeof(short));

    NSLog(@"Init Speex decoder success frame_size = %d",dec_frame_size);

    //init rtmp
    pPlayRtmp = RTMP_Alloc();
    RTMP_Init(pPlayRtmp);
    NSLog(@"Play RTMP_Init %@\n", rtmpURL);

    if (!RTMP_SetupURL(pPlayRtmp, (char*)[rtmpURL UTF8String])) {
        NSLog(@"Play RTMP_SetupURL error\n");
        if(self.rtmpDelegate) {
            [self.rtmpDelegate evenCallbackWithEvent:2002];
        }
        break;
    }

    if (!RTMP_Connect(pPlayRtmp, NULL) || !RTMP_ConnectStream(pPlayRtmp, 0)) {
        NSLog(@"Play RTMP_Connect or RTMP_ConnectStream error\n");
        if(self.rtmpDelegate) {
            [self.rtmpDelegate evenCallbackWithEvent:2002];
        }
        break;
    }

    if(self.rtmpDelegate) {
        [self.rtmpDelegate evenCallbackWithEvent:2001];
    }
    NSLog(@"Player RTMP_Connected \n");

    RTMPPacket rtmp_pakt = {0};
    isStartPlay = YES;
    while (isStartPlay && RTMP_ReadPacket(pPlayRtmp, &rtmp_pakt)) {
        if (RTMPPacket_IsReady(&rtmp_pakt)) {
            if (!rtmp_pakt.m_nBodySize) {
                continue;
            }
            if (rtmp_pakt.m_packetType == RTMP_PACKET_TYPE_AUDIO) {
                NSLog(@"Audio size = %d head = %d time = %d", rtmp_pakt.m_nBodySize, rtmp_pakt.m_body[0], rtmp_pakt.m_nTimeStamp);
                speex_bits_read_from(&dbits, rtmp_pakt.m_body + 1, rtmp_pakt.m_nBodySize - 1);
                speex_decode_int(dec_state, &dbits, input_buffer);  //audioData in the input_buffer
                //do something...



            } else if (rtmp_pakt.m_packetType == RTMP_PACKET_TYPE_VIDEO) {
                // 处理视频数据包
            } else if (rtmp_pakt.m_packetType == RTMP_PACKET_TYPE_INVOKE) {
                // 处理invoke包
                NSLog(@"RTMP_PACKET_TYPE_INVOKE");
                RTMP_ClientPacket(pPlayRtmp,&rtmp_pakt);
            } else if (rtmp_pakt.m_packetType == RTMP_PACKET_TYPE_INFO) {
                // 处理信息包
                //NSLog(@"RTMP_PACKET_TYPE_INFO");
            } else if (rtmp_pakt.m_packetType == RTMP_PACKET_TYPE_FLASH_VIDEO) {
                // 其他数据
                int index = 0;
                while (1) {
                    int StreamType; //1-byte
                    int MediaSize; //3-byte
                    int TiMMER; //3-byte
                    int Reserve; //4-byte
                    char* MediaData; //MediaSize-byte
                    int TagLen; //4-byte

                    StreamType = rtmp_pakt.m_body[index];
                    index += 1;
                    MediaSize = bigThreeByteToInt(rtmp_pakt.m_body + index);
                    index += 3;
                    TiMMER = bigThreeByteToInt(rtmp_pakt.m_body + index);
                    index += 3;
                    Reserve = bigFourByteToInt(rtmp_pakt.m_body + index);
                    index += 4;
                    MediaData = rtmp_pakt.m_body + index;
                    index += MediaSize;
                    TagLen = bigFourByteToInt(rtmp_pakt.m_body + index);
                    index += 4;
                    //NSLog(@"bodySize:%d   index:%d",rtmp_pakt.m_nBodySize,index);
                    //LOGI("StreamType:%d MediaSize:%d  TiMMER:%d TagLen:%d\n", StreamType, MediaSize, TiMMER, TagLen);
                    if (StreamType == 0x08) {
                        //音频包
                        //int MediaSize = bigThreeByteToInt(rtmp_pakt.m_body+1);
                        //  LOGI("FLASH audio size:%d  head:%d time:%d\n", MediaSize, MediaData[0], TiMMER);
                        speex_bits_read_from(&dbits, MediaData + 1, MediaSize - 1);
                        speex_decode_int(dec_state, &dbits, input_buffer);

                        //[mAudioPlayer putAudioData:input_buffer];
                        //  putAudioQueue(output_buffer,dec_frame_size);
                    } else if (StreamType == 0x09) {
                        //视频包
                        //  LOGI( "video size:%d  head:%d\n", MediaSize, MediaData[0]);
                    }
                    if (rtmp_pakt.m_nBodySize == index) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            RTMPPacket_Free(&rtmp_pakt);
        }
    }
    if (isStartPlay) {
        if(self.rtmpDelegate) {
            [self.rtmpDelegate evenCallbackWithEvent:2005];
        }
        isStartPlay = NO;
    }
} while (0);
[mAudioPlayer stopPlay];
if (self.rtmpDelegate) {
    [self.rtmpDelegate evenCallbackWithEvent:2004];
}
if (RTMP_IsConnected(pPlayRtmp)) {
    RTMP_Close(pPlayRtmp);
}
RTMP_Free(pPlayRtmp);
free(input_buffer);
speex_bits_destroy(&dbits);
speex_decoder_destroy(dec_state);
```

}

This is my custom method. RtmpURL is a NSString'S object, it is a stream server address. Use this method, I can get the encoded of audio stream from the server, after that, I use speex decoder to decode the data that I got, just like this:

```
//init speex decoder and config;
    speex_bits_init(&dbits);
    dec_state = speex_decoder_init(&speex_wb_mode);

    speex_decoder_ctl(dec_state, SPEEX_GET_FRAME_SIZE, &dec_frame_size);

    input_buffer = malloc(dec_frame_size * sizeof(short));

    NSLog(@"Init Speex decoder success frame_size = %d",dec_frame_size);
 if (rtmp_pakt.m_packetType == RTMP_PACKET_TYPE_AUDIO) {
                NSLog(@"Audio size = %d head = %d time = %d", rtmp_pakt.m_nBodySize, rtmp_pakt.m_body[0], rtmp_pakt.m_nTimeStamp);
                speex_bits_read_from(&dbits, rtmp_pakt.m_body + 1, rtmp_pakt.m_nBodySize - 1);
                speex_decode_int(dec_state, &dbits, input_buffer);  //audioData in the input_buffer
                //do something...



            }
```

Now, decoded of audio data are stored in the input_buffer, and this is my confusion. How do I use the AudioUnit to play the audio data.And this is my playback callback function:

```
OSStatus playCallback(void                            *inRefCon,
                  AudioUnitRenderActionFlags      *ioActionFlags,
                  const AudioTimeStamp            *inTimeStamp,
                  UInt32                          inBusNumber,
                  UInt32                          inNumberFrames,
                  AudioBufferList                 *ioData){
AudioPlayer *THIS = (__bridge AudioPlayer *)inRefCon;
//How do I use the AudioUnit to play the audio stream from server?

return noErr;
```

}

I hope some friends to solve my confusion, if you were used the audioUnit, Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your playCallback, you need to copy the audio into the buffer `ioData`. 
 For example

```
memcpy (ioData->mBuffers[0].mData,  input_buffer + offset, numBytes );
// increase offset based on how many frames it requests.
```

The input variable `inNumberFrames` is the number of frames that it is ready for.  This might be less than the number of frames in input_buffer.  So you need to keep track of your play position.

I do not know your audio format this specified in your audio stream basic description.  You need to calculate how many bytes need copied considering mono/stereo, number of bytes per channel, and of course `inNumberFrames`.

Answer (score 0):

There are some very good resources here [link](http://atastypixel.com/blog/using-remoteio-audio-unit/)